# Yii CMaskedTextField with one or two digits 0-99 (quantity)

Tags: input, yii

I'm trying to make `CMaskedTextField` as quantity input field with base quantity = 0, and maximum = 99.
Can't figure out the mask and/or `charMap`.

I've tried:

```
$this->widget('CMaskedTextField', array(
                'model' => $position,
                'attribute' => 'Quantity',
                'mask' => '99',
                'value' => $currentQuantity,
                'htmlOptions' => array('size' => 2, 'maxlength'=>2, 'minlength'=>1)
        ), true);
```

but this mask means there must be only 2 digits

Optional (i guess js will do the work if cmaskedtextfield not): when user clears input it should converts to '0'.

Comment: could you post in your question what you've already tried both in view and controller/action?

Answer (score 0):

Mask might be set thru regex: 
`\d{1,2}`
In model rules() you might define:

```
array('attributeName', 'match', 'pattern' => '/\d{1,2}/', 
'message' => '{attribute} can only contain digits from 0 to 99'),
```

There is no convertion to 0 but the explicit message for user.

Comment: the mask property of CMaskedTextField is not working correctly with value of    \d{1,2}

Comment: @SergeyLobanov, you seems have extended `CHtml::textField` into `CMaskedTextField`. Is it really needed? Why not just use validation with a rule on regex pattern? Are you familiar with regex?